# Unable to set Image from Resource to Custom ImageView in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, view, xamarin.android, imageview

I am able to set image in Non-Custom `ImageView` but unable to set Image in `Custom ImageView`, app loads successfully but unable to see the `Image`, below is the code.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{


    public ImageTestView imageView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        imageView = FindViewById<ImageTestView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.line_indent);

    }
}

<RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ImageViewTestProject.ImageTestView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/imageView1" />


</RelativeLayout>

public class ImageTestView : ImageView
{
    public ImageTestView(Context context,IAttributeSet attr) :
        base(context,attr)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: first thing you not doing anything in custom ImageTestView class.

Comment: If use your code , it will have a problem.There will have no constructors in your custom imageview.You can refer to G.hakim's answer.

Comment: i used hakim's code but same problem

Comment: Why don't you try to move the image to drawable folder and then check if using it from that folder works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

In the end, adding the image background through XML ended up solving the issue.

```
android:background="@mipmap/imagename"
```

---

Well I think the reason it's not working is that of the unavailable constructors and improper initialization

```
  public class ImageTestView : ImageView
  {
    Context mContext;
    public ImageTestView (Context context) : base(context)
    {
        init(context, null);
    }

    public ImageTestView (Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageTestView (Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageTestView (Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context ctx, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        mContext = ctx;
    }
  }
```

Then use this custom imageview in your app like:

```
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageViewTestProject.ImageTestView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And then you can set the image resource to it like this:

```
    var imageView = FindViewById<ImageTestView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
    imageView?.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.line_indent);
```

Revert in case this does not work or in case of queries

Comment: Did you check if the image view was drawn on the screen or not? This could be an issue with your image and not the image container you know, try setting a background colour to it instead and comment this `imageView?.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.line_indent);` and see if the ImageView is there

Comment: Yep, it is working with normal `ImageView` but not with custom imageview, but i think image is loaded but not visible.

Comment: i have set ImageView background color to red and color is showing.

Comment: So the problem is with setting the image and not with your ImageView I would suggest you try setting the background property from XML and see if that helps!  `android:background="@mipmap/imagename"`

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS If so I would suggest you mark this as the right answer.

Comment: no. the comment is right, the answer is basically not correct and there is no need of dumping all the constructors in it.

Answer (score 0):

1.First thing you not doing anything in custom **ImageTestView** class.

2.And setting the image Resource is wrong.either you have to taking from Drawable  folder it should be.

```
imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.line_indent);
```

I don't know in Xamarin Android.But if you know Android please refer this Example.it's bit similar to xamarin Android

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/extendsImageView.htm